# React - Blank page after building and deploying app to IIS

Tags: reactjs, iis, deployment, web-deployment

After I built and deployed my React App (initally built with Create-React-App) on IIS server, Chrome shows a blank page, 304 OK, and no errors as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRGez.jpg

How to resolve this?

When I Debug the app after deploying, I see that the debugger hits all my breakpoints in App.tsx (where my routes are) but not in any of route components.

I don't even know how to debug this issue because it is not throwing any errors.

I set `"private": false, "homepage": "."` in package.json.
I installed URL Rewrite module and added the below web.config file to the App's public folder so that the app works with React Router, but it made no difference:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration>  
    <system.webServer>  
        <rewrite>  
            <rules>  
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">  
                    <match url=".*" />  
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">  
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />  
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />  
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />  
                    </conditions>  
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />  
                </rule>  
            </rules>  
        </rewrite>  
    </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: For IIS beginners, please deploy as a site, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis About how to deploy as an IIS application, use search engines to learn more.

Comment: `https://imgur.com/a/W2JunFc` what is your project structure? what is this URL requesting? You can try using failed request tracing to view detailed request information, this will generate detail log file, which may help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Could you solve it? Im having the same problem.